# proof of log derivative using implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

How would you use implicit differentiation and the fact that $\log_b x$ is the inverse of $b^x$ to prove that $$\frac {d}{dx} (\log_b x) =\frac{1}{(\ln b)x}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) , which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, when you post a question here, you should show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  In this case, you could tell us what you know.  For instance, do you know the derivative of $\log_e x$ or how logarithmic differentiation works? Writing down what you know may help you make progress on the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we  would simply observe that since $\ln(b)$ is a constant:

$$\log_b (x)= \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)} $$
$$ \frac{d \log_b (x)}{dx}= \frac{1}{ \ln(b) x} $$
Since we know how to derive $\ln(x)$, its derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$. But now we wish to use that the logarithm is the inverse of the exponent, then we need to use the rules for exponents. We know how to derive $e^x$ this will be a key property of our method.

Call $u=\log_b (x)$ then since $e^{\ln(b)}=b$ we can write:
$$ x= b^u=e^{\ln(b)u} $$
We derive both sides with respect to $x$ using implicit differentiation and the chain rule ($\frac{d}{dx}e^{ax}= a e^{ax}$) remembering that $u$ depends on $x$.:
$$ 1= e^{\ln(b) u} \cdot (\ln(b) \frac{d u}{d x} )$$
So now we separate $\frac{d u}{d x}$ from the other terms and get:

$$\frac{d u}{ d x}= \frac{1}{\ln (b) e^{\ln(b) u}}= \frac{1}{\ln(b) x} $$

Comment: Type `$\log_b x$` and `$\ln x$` to produce $\log_b x$ and $\ln x$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: set $y=\log_b (x)$
so $$x=b^y$$
Apply natural logarithm to both sides:
$$\ln(x)=\ln\left(b^y\right)$$
$$\ln(x)=y\ln(b)$$
From here, use implicit differentiation (Note: $\ln(b)$ is a constant)